# Elements of symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove that (123) is not a cube of any element in $S_n$. Is it true in general that any $p$ cycle, $p$ an odd prime, can't be written as a $p^{th}$ power of any element in $S_n$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, taking a $p$-th power of any permutation will alter its cycle structure precisely by breaking up any cycles with a length $l$ divisible by $p$ into $p$ separate cycles with length $l/p$ (other cycles lengths are unaffected). As a consequence, any resulting cycles lengths that are (still) divisible by $p$ will necessarily occur with a multiplicity divisible by$~p$. In particular the result cannot be (or contain) a single $p$-cycle. And there is no need to restrict to *odd* primes, $p=2$ will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose that $\sigma^{3} = (123)$. Take a cycle decomposition for $\sigma$ and consider the possibilities.